# Butterfly Chart using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a butterfly chart using Highcharts. I want to plot it as
[image: Butterfly Chart]

The Code is as follows

```
// Data gathered from http://populationpyramid.net/germany/2015/
$(function () {
// Age categories
var categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
        '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
        '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
        '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
        '95-99', '100 + '];
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Population pyramid for Germany, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://populationpyramid.net/germany/2015/">Population Pyramids of the World from 1950 to 2100</a>'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, /*{ // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }*/],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: [-2.2, -2.2, -2.3, -2.5, -2.7, -3.1, -3.2,
                -3.0, -3.2, -4.3, -4.4, -3.6, -3.1, -2.4,
                -2.5, -2.3, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, -0.0, -0.0]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [2.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 2.9,
                3.1, 4.1, 4.3, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 2.9, 2.9,
                1.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.0]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Here is my fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0xked93c/), how can I get my xAxis labels in between the series. Please guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this differently than morgan did, though that example is certainly useful.

I would do this as a standard bar chart, making use of multiple `yAxis` objects (one for each series), which also allows for using the `reversed` property of the left-facing series.

**Code Example:**

```
    yAxis: [{
        title: { text: null },
        width: 200,
        reversed: true
    },{
        offset: 0,
        title: { text: null },
        left: 300,
        width: 200
    }],
    series: [{
      yAxis: 0,
      data: [...]
    }, {
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [...]
    }]
```

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/L80cdxm0/

**Example Output:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi @jlriggs, can we've a Axis labels so that they can accommodate category names more than 10 characters. Plz check this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/L80cdxm0/3/)

Comment: The space available for the axis labels is entirely dependent on the `yAxis` position settings. If you change the `width` and `left` settings, you can create as much or as little space as you want. Also, if you center the label, whether by CSS, or using the `useHTML` feature, they will better use the space.

Comment: Just to emphasize, scales in the bar chart with two axes and the columnrange are different - so is the "data story", even the charts look similar. This is a great chart, though -  represents data much cleaner the the chart from the picture.

Comment: @GeekExplorer,  **morganfree** - it's a very good point that the each axis in my example had a different scale. The two y axes in this type of chart should always have the same scale. I updated the code with a snippet to set the max of each axis to the max of the two data sets, updated the axis spacing and label settings per your previous comment, and updated the attached image and fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

An [inverted columnrange](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange) chart combines with the [cross-specific-values](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values) plugin is a way to go. A column range chart allows you to specify position of the columns and make the space for labels. The plugin moves the axis to the center of the chart.

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
      text: 'Butterfly Chart Example'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>'
    },

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true,
        marginTop: 100
    },

    legend: {
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 60,
      x: -25,
      itemDistance: 50
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['G7', 'A8', 'V9', 'V4', 'V3', 'V1', 'V5'],
        crossing: 118,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
    },

    yAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      tickInterval: 50,
      min: 0,
      max: 250,
      lineWidth: 1,
      title: {
        text: null
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        grouping: false
      }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'South',
        color: 'blue',
        data: [
          [55, 100],
          [60, 100],
          [65, 100],
          [55, 100],
          [75, 100],
          [52, 100],
          [60, 100]
        ]
    }, {
      name: 'North',
      color: 'orange',
      data: [
        [120, 170],
        [120, 150],
        [120, 175],
        [120, 130],
        [120, 125],
        [120, 148],
        [120, 145]
      ]
    }]

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7d4mrhuv/

Comment: As you agreed, I felt @jlbriggs answer tells complete story and appreciate your effort for helping me, people like u motivate me to take up such different tasks. Thank you so much :)