# Highcharts | Graph with category names in the middle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to set up a graph for a web application, and I decided to use Highcharts because it seems to be the most flexible. I managed to create what I wanted, but I can't do it in one graphic, I have to create two.

My goal is to have a bar graph, with negative values on the left and positive values on the right, and category names in the middle (and being able to place HTML in it but it's secondary).

Here is the link to what I have [today](https://jsfiddle.net/GGermain/9j9cgb0p/1/):

```
$(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart : {
            type : 'bar'
        },
        title : { text : '' },
        subtitle : { text : '' },
        plotOptions : {
            bar : { dataLabels : { enabled : true }}
        },
        legend : { enabled : false },
        credits : { enabled : false },
        yAxis : {         
            title : false,
            opposite : true
        },
        xAxis : {
            categories : ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
            labels : { format : "" },
            type : "category",
            visible : false,
            title : false,
            showEmpty: false,
            reversed : true
        }
    });

    // Graphique gauche (négatifs)
    var leftChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo: 'gphLeft' },
        yAxis: { reversed : false },
        xAxis: { opposite : true },
        series : [{
            data : [null, -150, null, null, -680]
        }]
    });

    // Graphique droite (positifs)
    var rightChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo: 'gphRight' },
        yAxis: { reversed : false },
        xAxis: { opposite : false },
        series : [{
            data : [180, null, 258, 487, null]
        }]
    });
});
```

I have tried different techniques and answers found on the Internet, but I can't find a solution.

(I hope you understand, because I use a translator)

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I don't think Highcharts will have an easy way of doing that. For your needs, I think you are on the right path. What we can get out of the box with Highcharts, afaik, is using the `offset` property on `xAxis`. But the result is not good: https://jsfiddle.net/fnqxhybb/

Comment: Check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584716/butterfly-chart-using-highcharts

Comment: @JoãoMenighin : Thank you for this information.

Comment: @morganfree : Thanks for the link. I'll check it out.